# Google Places Autocomplete not working after closing the application

Tags: android, google-places-api

I tried to follow the tutorial from [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#add_an_autocomplete_widget), which was from scratch, and it works fine. But when I used it on the app I'm currently working, it doesn't work properly. It will only work after I run the app but when I close the app and run it again, autocomplete is not working and the widget immediately close. Hope you guys help me, looking forward to your suggestions and comments. Thanks :D

Comment: Add your code. That can give better idea of mistake.

Comment: I just followed the tutorial from developers.google.com and even the logcat don't show anything as if the app is not connected to it.

Comment: @Dipali shah. Just clearing the problem.
I only run the app once, it works fine after that. But when I close the app and open it again and try to use the autocomplete widget, now it doesn't work..

Comment: can you post code and flow of your application @Kim

Comment: When the widget "immediately closes" does onActivityResult() get called with an error? If it does, that might give you a clue as to what's going on.

Comment: I don't know what happen but after a day I updated my android studio and it works properly. Thanks for your concern guys..